# Odd Question about docx to pdf conversion

Tags: c#, pdf, openxml, docx

I have a program that generates long word documents using c# and an intermediate XML file. When I then try to convert the docx file to pdf the images get moved (only images and nothing else). However (this is the weird part) if I use word and physically move the images slightly from where the program placed them and then try and convert to pdf it works fine. My question is what is changing when I move the images myself?

I understand this a highly unusual question and would greatly appreciate any insite  at all.

Comment: Add your question is specific to the documents you generate *using c# and an intermediate XML file*,  you should share an example of such a file to enable people to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What are you using to do the conversion, are you using Word or some code?

Comment: The conversion is usually done using libre office but every other converter used yields the same results, I just cant figure out what changes when I move the images before attempting the conversion. Unfortunately I cannot show the code.

Comment: When you add images in Word, you can embed them or link them.  I guess your images are linked, not embedded?